# Create Schedule(Delayed) Recurring job using hangfire in asp.net forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, delayed-job, hangfire, recurring

I want to create a recurring job with Hangfire but I want it to be delayed and start at a certain date.
For example I will create a job that do a task every week but I want this task to start after 3 days!

After searching I couldn't come to something that can do both delayed task and make it recurring at the same time.

I just started using hangfire today so I don't have much experience using it yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hangfire offers the possibility to create recurring jobs in this way:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
    () => myRecurringJob(),
    Cron.Daily);
```

However as you mentioned this does not allow to postpone the date where the first occurrence will start. To work around this, I suggest to use a scheduled job to create your recurring job at a later time:

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => myRecurringJobCreation(), 
                       new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2017,2,10)));

//...
public void myRecurringJobCreation() {
    RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
        () => myRecurringJob(),
        Cron.Daily);
}
```

Comment: That was the first thing that came across my mind, but I thought there may be something else using the Api that can directly address this issue!

Comment: @MuhammadNour I think the only other option is to create the recurring job right away and prevent execution directly in `myRecurringJob` but this is quite ugly. I don't know of a nicer way to achieve this in the API